# What could cause a COM component to be registered (shows in visual studio reference COM section) but not visible in office ActiveX components?

Tags: c#, com, activex, office-interop, com-interop

I'm trying to add a custom ActiveX component to a PowerPoint slide, i've been trying many things, my powerpoint version is 32 bit, now i'm trying to make it as simple as possible. The project is AnyCPU and .net 4.7.

VSTO does not fit my needs so this is not an option (as far as i could find it doesn't let you add custom controls to slides, which i need)

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[Guid("87622EEA-5A6A-4F1B-A56A-AC0F88603EF6")]
public interface IBasicActiveXSampleInterface
{
    string testOne();
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("B2B334B3-2785-40C6-A3B9-1CEF9D7D4D94")]
[ProgId("EKATONXSampleProg")]
public class BasicActiveXSample : IBasicActiveXSampleInterface
{
    public string testOne()
    {
        return "test 1234";
    }
}
```

Also declared at the assembly level :

```
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
```

I disabled registering for COM in the project properties and added postbuild event thinking it may be a bitness issue so the project gets registered by both .net 4 regasm (framework and framework 64).

The component shows in the list of COM components in add reference in visual studio but no matter what i do it won't show in powerpoint developper mode under other controls (yet other controls work just fine, i can add the media player to a slide for example).

Edit : the end goal is to have a visible winform control to host WPF content, but once i'll have an activeX control written in C# registered i'll feel more at home, i tried going for it from the start following the scarce tutorials (and pretty much no documentation) on the subject, all failed except once my control showed in the list randomly and crashed when added with an error saying powerpoint couldn't read the registry.

List of pages i've looked at and reproduced to no avail :

https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/comcom/article.php/c16257/Create-an-ActiveX-using-a-Csharp-Usercontrol.htm

https://codedocu.com/Office-365/Office/COM-Controls/Code_colon_-Create-your-own-ActiveX-Component-in-Visual-Studio-2017-and-Office-2016-365?2075

https://codedocu.com/Details_mobile?d=2382&z=1&t=Create+C%23+COM+Control+for+Office

Comment: @HansPassant sorry posted too early, tried to make a minimal example but have add the same issue reprodcing (and even downloading and running as is) all the sample links i give in my edit which are supposed to be activex controls

Comment: @HansPassant Also i can't seem to reference it in the vba editor in the way it was suggested on the tutorial i found (code editor => components => components manager's list is empty, not sure how to register the TLB)

Comment: Well, those are indeed ActiveX controls.  They are hard to get right because they require a custom [ComRegisterFunction] in order to write the "Control" registry key.  So you left the most-likely-to-be-wrong part of your project out of your snippet.  98.37% odds that is where the problem is located.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried the most recent one (second link), downloaded it, ran it as is (exception made of running VS as administrator so it can register for interop) and the control doesn't show up, it contains register/unregister functions and is the only viable example i could find that was recent. I'd love to dig this issue by myself but i can't find anything that isn't absolutely ancient about activex development in .net sadly. Do you see anything wrong with the second link (the vs 2017/office 2016 one) that could cause the issue?

Comment: I can't see your screen from here.  I posted my own back-to-basics solution a decade ago, something else to try: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2fe50909-f7f8-4500-a99c-34de2ef567f6/activex-control-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral